# A problem with Gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem Source : (Bangladesh Math Olympiad )

The problem :

The integral $Z(0)=\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} \, dx= \sqrt{\pi}$, the integral $Z(j)=\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-x^{2}+jx} \, dx$; where $j$ is not a function of $x$, is $Z(j)=e^{j^2/4} Z(0)$

Show that
$$d\frac 1 {Z(0)}\int^\infty_{-\infty} x^{2n} e^{-x^2} \, dx= \frac {(2n-1)!!}{2^n}$$

where $(2n-1)!!$ is defined as $(2n-1)(2n-3)\times\cdots\times3\times 1$

My approach :
$x^2=z$ variable change, then the integral becomes gamma function;but what to next ?

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the task. You say you want to show that $\dfrac 1 {Z(0)}=\int x^{2n} e^{-x^2} dx= \dfrac {(2n-1)!!}{2^n}$, but $\frac{1}{Z(0)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ is just a constant. Where's that $n$ coming from?

Comment: @GhostAmarth: In addition, the third integrals is indefinite.

Comment: but it has solution , as it is national Olympiad problem , third indefinite for my typing mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the integrand inside the last integral is an odd function, we can rewrite it as follows:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=2\int_0^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x
$$

Now, we let $x=\sqrt{t}$ so that $\mathrm{d}x={1\over2}t^{-1/2}\mathrm{d}t$:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty t^{n-{1\over2}}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t=\Gamma\left(n-{1\over2}+1\right)
$$

We know that Gamma function has an identity that $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$, so we can rewrite the Gamma function by

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma\left(n-{1\over2}+1\right)
&=\left(n-{1\over2}\right)\left(n-1-{1\over2}\right)\cdots\left(1-{1\over2}\right)\Gamma\left(1\over2\right) \\
&=\Gamma\left(1\over2\right)\prod_{k=1}^n\left(k-{1\over2}\right) \\
&=2^{-n}\Gamma\left(1\over2\right)\prod_{k=1}^n\left[2\left(k-{1\over2}\right)\right] \\
&=2^{-n}\Gamma\left(1\over2\right)\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1) \\
&=2^{-n}\Gamma\left(1\over2\right)(2n-1)!! \\
&={\Gamma\left(1\over2\right)(2n-1)!!\over2^n} \\
&={\sqrt\pi(2n-1)!!\over2^n}
\end{aligned}
$$

The last equation follows from the fact that $\Gamma\left(1\over2\right)=\sqrt\pi$. Given that the Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt\pi$, we come to the result:

$$
{1\over\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt\pi(2n-1)!!\over2^n}={(2n-1)!!\over2^n}
$$